# Show .txt file line by line in App Inventor 2

Tags: android, file, app-inventor

I would like to read a txt file and show line by line in **App Inventor 2**,  but I don't know which components/blocks to use.

Something like these

> choose .txt for reading > show only first line > press button > show
>   second line

This is Blocks that I try to use and still no idea
[Sorry, If it didn't help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdPtP.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please first [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). And concerning your question: what about using the `File` component? I recommend you to first [do the tutorials](http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/ai2/tutorials.html) to learn the basics...

Comment: @Taifun Sorry But Try it already

Comment: what about *editing* your question and adding a screenshot of *what* you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ploy, you can do as below:

[image]

Firstly, you need to create global empty list. Next, global LineIndex variable which indicate the number of lines that will be shown. Lastly, you have to configure the MaxIndex number that refer to maximum lines in your file.

Then, at Screen1.Initialize just call File1.ReadFrom function. You can specify your own file name. Yet, please make sure it is saved in .csv format. The contain of the file will be something such below:

[image]

In this example, I'm using two different buttons. One button to read the file and another button to reset the global LineIndex countdown. From first image, you can see in when Read_Button.Click part, I have set the global LineIndex countdown to increase automatically by 1 after Read_Button is clicked.

Then, for safety reason, I have add another check "If and Else" statement. The Result_Label will only show the contain in the file if the LineIndex countdown is not exceed the maximum line in the file.

That's it.

Comment: It's say "Runtime Error"
Select list item: Attempt to get item number 3 of a list of length 0: ()
Note: You will not see another error reported for 5 seconds.
[Image](http://i.imgur.com/FAFUPKn.png)

Comment: You should you "List from csv table text" function in "when File1.GotText" part. Please see again my code from above image.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the bufferReader readLine method

```
 private BufferedReader mBufferedReader
         try { 
         InputStream mInputStream = openFileInput("file.txt");
         if ( inputStream != null ) {
                    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
                     mBufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

                    mInputStream.close();
            }
           }
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            onClick(View view){
                if(mBufferedReader.readLine()) != null ){
                 //show text using bufferedReader.readLine()
              }

        });
```

Comment: Thx but I use app inventor 2 and don't know how to add code into it